# I had a problem that the styles do not change although I made some changes in css file

Tags: python, html, css, flask, web

**My folder structure**

```
Food Delivery App/
  app.py
  static/
    stylesheets/
      base.css
  templates/
    base.html
```

**base.css**

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width:100%;
}
body {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width:600px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right:0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.navbar{
    background-color:skyblue;
}
.nav-link{
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
.form-inline{
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
.login_btn{
    padding-left:50px;
}
```

**base.html**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/base.css') }}" />
{% block head %} 
{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg">
        <a class="navbar-brand"><a class="nav-link" href="#homepage">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/ufood.png')}}" alt="ufood logo" width="50" height="50">
        </a>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar_options">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Mission</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Restaurants</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2 search_food" placeholder="Browse by cuisines">
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
           <a class="login_btn" href="">Login</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap


app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('homepage.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

[image: Flask Web app]

I have a problem that when I made any changes in `base.css` and run the python script, the `base.html` template does not update according the styles set in the css file. May I ask any tricks that I missed so the template could not follow the styles according to the css file? For example I saved my css file that set the background-color `.navbar` to skyblue but when I refresh the web template it still shows black color instead of skyblue. Also the padding does not follow accordingly is there a problem that I missed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Reason : when you just refresh the web template all the static files are just coming for your browser cache.

Issue Solution : Try using hard reload to refresh the web page, so that all your templates and CSS will be loaded again.

Instead of Refresh( F5 ) try below command in respective system :

Windows users: hold down Ctrl and then press F5 on your keyboard.
Mac users: hold down Cmd and Shift and then press R on your keyboard.